# Move texts to the center

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to create a log in screen. But I cant move these 2 Labels in the mid of the screen. I'm sure you can help me guys :) See pics in the Link.

https://ibb.co/vP1ydvk
https://ibb.co/crWh94n

```
def show_welcome_message(self):
    vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    horizontal_layout = QHBoxLayout()
    group_box = QGroupBox()

    welcome_label = QLabel("Welcome!")
    user_label = QLabel("Logged in as test test test")
    welcome_label.setFont(QFont("Times", 20))

    vertical_layout.addStretch(1)
    vertical_layout.addWidget(welcome_label)
    vertical_layout.addWidget(user_label)
    vertical_layout.addStretch(1)

    horizontal_layout.addStretch(1)
    horizontal_layout.addLayout(vertical_layout)
    horizontal_layout.addStretch(1)

    group_box.setLayout(horizontal_layout)
    self.MainWindow.setCentralWidget(group_box)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a widget with two centered labels:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('This is a label')
    label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('This is another label')
    # center text within labels
    label1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    label2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
    # center labels within layout
    layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    layout.addWidget(label1)
    layout.addWidget(label2)

    widget.resize(400,400)

    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: screenshot of centered labels]

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui  import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)

        group_box = QGroupBox()
        grid.addWidget(group_box)

        self.vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout() 
        group_box.setLayout(self.vertical_layout)

        self.show_welcome_message()

    def show_welcome_message(self):
        welcome_label = QLabel("Welcome!", alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        welcome_label.setFont(QFont("Times", 20))
        user_label = QLabel("Logged in as test test test", alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.vertical_layout.addStretch(1)
        self.vertical_layout.addWidget(welcome_label)
        self.vertical_layout.addWidget(user_label)
        self.vertical_layout.addStretch(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]